Calculate the mean for date and hour from a multi year dataframe in r
I have a data frame that looks like this:
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1559347200, 1559350800, 
1559354400, 1559358000, 1559361600, 1559365200, 1559368800, 1559372400, 
1559376000, 1559379600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), BUSwt = c(77.8154, 77.2538, 76.9325, 76.81235, 76.6544, 
76.3403, 76.16165, 76.22375, 76.47035, 76.74395), MBwt = c(78.3653, 
78.53495, 78.6074, 78.30725, 78.0368, 77.9477, 77.8946, 77.927, 
78.12455, 78.23615), SUSwt = c(76.2575, 76.0055, 75.7265, 75.425, 
75.137, 74.849, 74.651, 74.624, 74.696, 74.8535)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

It has 5 years of datetime data for the three variable columns "BUSwt", "MBwt", and "SUSwt". I want to calculate the mean, min, and max of of these variable for each specific date and hour over the course of the 5 years of data. An example of this data would look like:



datetime
BUSwt_mean
BUSwt_max
BUSwt_min
MBwt_mean
MBwt_max
MBwt_min
SUSwt_mean
SUSwt_max
SUSwt_min




06-01 00:00:00
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx


06-01 01:00:00
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx


06-01 02:00:00
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx


06-01 03:00:00
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx


06-01 04:00:00
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx



My current code to make the data frame looks like this:
WaterData <- BUSdata %>%
  left_join(MBdata, by = "datetime") %>%
  left_join(SUSdata, by = "datetime")

Is there a way to do this continuing in a pipe?

This question is different because the main objective is not how to aggregate multiple columns but how how to aggregate these column's values by "mm-dd hh:mm:ss" for the span the entirety of the data set.

I don't understand either. Does your data has multiple rows for each hour ( your example does not reflect that) ? If its the case, you can round by hour. See this section of R for Data Science  : https://r4ds.hadley.nz/datetimes#rounding

How many data sets do you have, 3? Your problem description does not suggest left_join (nor any other kind of join) as a solution.

Is the problem that you want to group by month/day/hour but not by year?

Correct, I want to look at mean, max, and min by month/day/hour but not year.

Another way to get what you need, using dplyr's handy across() function:
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(month = month(datetime),
         day = day(datetime),
         hour = hour(datetime)) %>%
  group_by(month, day, hour) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c("BUSwt", "MBwt", "SUSwt"),
                   .fns = list("min" = min, "mean" = mean, "max" = max))) %>%
  ungroup()

This solution separates month, day, and hour into their own columns.  If you really need a date format (e.g., for plotting purposes), then you can coerce everything to the same year (doesn't matter what year it is), like this:
df %>%
  mutate(datetime = `year<-`(datetime, 2000)) %>%
  group_by(datetime) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c("BUSwt", "MBwt", "SUSwt"),
                   .fns = list("min" = min, "mean" = mean, "max" = max))) %>%
  ungroup()


Here is a solution, if I understand the problem correctly.
I assume the problem is to compute aggregated statistics by date/hour.
library(tidyverse)

BUSdata %>%
  pivot_longer(-datetime) %>%
  mutate(datehour = format(datetime, "%m-%d %H")) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
    min = min(value, na.rm = TRUE),
    max = max(value, na.rm = TRUE),
    .by = c(datehour, name)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(datehour, name), names_to = "stats") %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = datehour,
    names_from = c(name, stats),
    values_from = value
  )

